# New to using ActiveAdmin and need to display Categories in Rails 4 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I'm building an app using ActiveAdmin gem for the first time.

There is this one thing I can't yet figure out.

I have Products and each product is in a Category.

I do it like this.

in `product.rb` model

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :category
    belongs_to :page


        validates :title, :description, presence: true
        validates :price_usd, :price_isl, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0.01}
        validates :title, uniqueness: true


     has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "500x500#", thumb: "100x100#" }
     validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
 end
```

And in `category.rb` model

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :products
  has_many :pages

end
```

And in `app/admin/product.rb` the code is like.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Product do

  permit_params :title, :description, :image, :price_usd, :price_isl

end
```

And in `app/admin/category.rb`it is like

```
ActiveAdmin.register Category do

  permit_params :name

end
```

In the ActiveAdmin Panel the user can import Products and Create Categories
but when I want to display the products and categories on the web page, something isn´t working and neither products nor categories are displaying.

On the `views/pages/index.html.erb` the Products should be lining up as seen in the code below. But they are not.

in `views/pages/index.html.erb`

```
<div class="container-fluid">

     <% @products.each_slice(3) do |products_group| %>
        <div class="row">
          <% products_group.each do |category, products| %>

            <% products.each_with_index do |product, index| %>
                <% if index == 0 %>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 center-block " >

                        <%= link_to category_path (category) do %>
                        <%= image_tag product.image, class: "img-responsive" %>
                        <% end %>
                    <div class="caption">
                        <p><%= product.category.name %></p>
                     </div> 
                    <% end %>
                    <% end %>
                    </div> 
                <% end %>
                </div>
            <% end %>

    </div>
```

In the _navbar.hml.erb partial I have this code to display the Categories in a dropdown. The category names are displayed, but when a category name is clicked it directs to an empty page showing no products.

this is the navbar code

```
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
       <% @categories.each do |category| %>
            <li><%= link_to category.name, category %></li>
        <% end %>     
   </ul>
```

and here is the code for the `views/categories/show.html`

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row product_top">

 <h1 ><%= @category.name %></h1>

    <% @products.each do |product| %>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 center-block " >

  <%= link_to product_path (product) do %>
                <%= image_tag product.image, class: "img-responsive" %>
            <% end %>

        <div class="product_description">

          <h5><%= link_to product.name, product %></h5>
          <p><%= product.description %></p>
          <p class="price"> <%= number_to_currency(product.price_usd, :precision => 0 )%> | <%= number_to_currency(product.price_isl.to_i, :unit => "kr", :precision => 0) %></p>
          <p><%= social_share_button_tag(products.name) %></p>

        </div>


      </div>
    <% end %>

  </div>
</div>

<%= link_to 'Back', root_path %>
```

The only thing that appears on the show page is the Category name.....

this is the `categories_controller.rb`

```
 class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
     before_action :set_category, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  def index
    @categories = Category.all
  end

   def show
    @products = @category.products
     @images  = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg", "4.jpg", "5.jpg"]
     @random_no = rand(5)
     @random_image = @images[@random_no]
  end

 private

    def set_category
      @category = Category.includes(:products).find(params[:id])
    end


    def category_params
      params.require(:category).permit(:name)
    end
end
```

this is the `products_controller.rb`

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


    private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_product
      @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:name, :description, :price_usd, :price_isl, :image, :category_id)
    end
 end
```

I'm feeling kind of lost here, been spending the whole day trying to figure this out and making the products appear in each category. This is the first time I'm doing this kind of thing using ActiveAdmin, so I believe that the problem lies there.

It would be very much appreciated if someone could guide me here. 
thanks in advance

Comment: Add `category_id` to the `permit_params` list in the `app/admin/product.rb` file

Comment: Thanks it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Inside active admin product.rb
You need to add

```
permit_params :title, :description, :image, :price_usd, :price_isl,:category_id
```

and here is how to display the names in the index

```
  index do
    column :id
    column :title
    column :description
    column "category" do |m|
      Category.find(m.category_ids).map(&:name).join(', ')
    end
    
    column :price_usd
    column :price_isl
    column :created_at
    actions
  end
```